# Trouble solving this coding puzzle using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, scope, closures

Instructions are as follows:

"Write a function that will find all the anagrams of a word from a list. You will be given two inputs a word and an array with words. You should return an array of all the anagrams or an empty array if there are none. For example:

anagrams('abba', ['aabb', 'abcd', 'bbaa', 'dada']) => ['aabb', 'bbaa']"

I snagged a snippet that takes the first parameter and delivers every combination of characters possible. My trouble now is figuring out how to match this array against the second parameter, and returning some results..

```js
function allAnagrams (word,words) {
  

  if (word.length < 2) {
    return [word];
  } else {
      var allAnswers = [];
      
      
      for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        var letter = word[i];
        var shorterWord = word.substr(0, i) + word.substr(i + 1, word.length - 1);
        var shortwordArray = allAnagrams(shorterWord);
        for (var j = 0; j < shortwordArray.length; j++) {
          allAnswers.push(letter + shortwordArray[j]);
          
        }
        
      }
      
      return allAnswers;
  }
  
}



allAnagrams("abc",["acb","cba","bac","bca"]);
```

My instinct was to split the word into an array, and then have another nested for loop to match what needs to be matched. However, I seem to have  run into some problems with handling the scope and keep breaking the function so I've turned to you bright minded people. If you have a moment, I would appreciate a hint of how to tackle this from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to see if any [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of your first string appears in the array.

A fast way to compare if two strings are permutations of one another is to sort the two strings and compare:

```
function stringSort(string) {
  return string.split('').sort().join('');
}

function isAnagram(first, second) {
  // are the two sorted strings equal, if so then anagram
  return stringSort(first) == stringSort(second);
}
```

Now, we can use these handy functions to help us build the final desired function:

```
function allAnagrams(word, words) {
  return words.filter(function(element) {
    return isAnagram(word, element);
  });
}
```

Note the use of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter), a very handy method for boiling an array down to a few values under some condition.

**Note** that I have not tested this so if there are any problems please ask.

Comment: It's good. Could be optimised by pre-calculating `stringSort(word)`.

Comment: @Amadan I realised when I was creating this that I had used the term 'fast' without making any attempts at all to optimise xD

Comment: That is cool, really good to know. If you don't mind explaining what exactly is the parameter 'element' pulling from? And would pre-calculating like Amadan said just be adding a line split/sorting 'word' to the allAnagrams function?

Comment: You can have a look at all the links I provide in my post @Benediah for example see here [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) for help with what `element` is

Comment: @Benediah you are also allwoed to implement and experiment with my code, try adding `console.log(element)` for example.

Comment: Understood, I appreciate your help! Thanks